# How to precisely control axis scale function in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot points on the interval x in [0, 4]. My function performs something interesting for very small values, so I would like to create a non-linear scale that would use more space for smaller values of x. Logarithmic scale would be a great solution, but the problem is that my x-axis must include 0, which is not part of logarithmic axis.

So I considered using a power scale. After some googling I came across the following solution.

```
def stratify(ax, power=2):
    f     = lambda x: (x + 1)**(1 / power)
    f_inv = lambda y: y**power - 1
    ax.set_xscale('function', functions=(f, f_inv))

x = np.linspace(0, 4, 100)
y = np.sqrt(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
stratify(ax, 2)

plt.show()
```

The function `stratify` changes the x-scale of the plot to the square root function. This looks kind of correct. Below is a minimal example plot corresponding to the above code (not actual data).

[image: Plot produced by the attached code]

I would like to have control over the nonlinearity in the x-scale, that is why I have introduced the `power` parameter. **However, when I change the power parameter to value different from 2, the plot does not change at all.** This is very surprising for me. I would appreciate if somebody could advise me how I can control the extent of non-linearity in x-axis. If possible, I would like it even more non-linear, making the interval [0, 0.5] take half of the plot.

**EDIT** While the current solution by @Thomas works as intended, the plotting routine throws a lot of errors when one attempts to do anything with it. For example, I would like to insert extra ticks, as the original only has integer ticks for whatever reason. Inserting extra ticks via `ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks() + [0.5])` results in an error `posx and posy should be finite values`. What is this error, and how can it be bypassed?

Comment: I adressed that **EDIT** in the comment to my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, there's a change when switching from `power=2` to `power=10`. Just be careful to edit it at the right position, i.e. when calling `stratify=X`.

Here's `power=2`:
[image]
Here's `power=10`:
[image]

However, here's another suggestion that is slightly more aggressive:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def stratify(ax, scale=1):
    f = lambda x: np.log(x / scale + 1)
    f_inv = lambda y: scale * (np.exp(y) - 1)
    ax.set_xscale('function', functions=(f, f_inv))


x = np.linspace(0, 4, 100)
y = np.sqrt(x)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3)
for i, scale in enumerate([10,1,0.1]):
    ax = axs[i]
    ax.set_title(f'Scale={scale}')
    ax.plot(x, y)
    stratify(ax, scale=scale)

plt.show()
```

Resulting in
[image]

Another option are [zoom regions](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/zoom_inset_axes.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-zoom-inset-axes-py).

Comment: Another option are zoom regions: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/zoom_inset_axes.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-zoom-inset-axes-py

Comment: Add that comment / link as an edit to your answer. Comments get deleted.

Comment: There is another problem. I would like to add extra ticks. But when I insert `ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks() + [0.5])`, I get an error `posx and posy should be finite values`

Comment: For me this works if I set the ticks **after** calling `stratify`.

Comment: Maybe a last comment on the overall idea: Just be aware that this really distorts your data a lot.

Comment: After some fighting I found the culprit. Matplotlib does not stick to the xrange of [0, 4] when plotting, it attempts to make a slightly wider range, e.g. [-0.05, 4.05] to have nice margins. However, the mapping you provided does not work for negative numbers as the logarithm blows up. I designed a more fancy function that performs y=x for negative numbers and the original function you suggested for positive numbers. Now there are no errors and everything seems to work.